# How to design the autocomplete suggestion box - jQuery - Django

Tags: html, jquery, django

I build an autocomplete function with jQuery and it's working fine but now I want to design the suggestion box which appears if you type in something. I also want to make some changes like how many results should be displayed.

```
$(function() {
    $("#search_input").autocomplete({
        source: "request",
        select: function (event, ui) { //item selected
            AutoCompleteSelectHandler(event, ui)
        },
        minLength: 3,
});
});

function AutoCompleteSelectHandler(event, ui)
{
var selectedObj = ui.item;
}
```

This is my jQuery function[image]

This is how the suggestion box looks like.

How can I design it ? I also want to adjust the amount of results which I get displayed.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to adjust the amount of results which I get displayed by filtering them in my python script.